# PS to PL on the X410

Tags: fpga, usrp, uhd

I have a few questions regarding the USRP X410 and wanted to see if anyone else has ran into the same issue.

To test out the product, I have created a program that will generate a random number,  I have also made a bitstream to do some operations on that number.   However, I cannot find any documentation on using the Arm processor within the device to pass the integer to the PL.

I have thought about using DMA to pass that information but I want to avoid using uhd for this application.   After researching how I could accomplish this, I wanted to use liberio to pass the integer to my bit stream but that was removed from UHDv4.0 and the X410 uses UHD 4.0+.   I thought about using DRAM but as it's not static it wouldn't be reliable to run on reboot.

My goal is to be able to communicate the random ints I generate to the PL from the onboard Linux OS within the device and keep away from UHD. Does anyone have any recommendations?

I have tried finding examples of communication without UHD libraries such as liberio but given the most recent updates, I haven't seen what Ettus is using instead

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.